# Identify Malaysian shrub with five-petaled white flowers and waxy lanceolate leaves

Tags: identification, shrubs

I need to identify the name of this plant for my school project. The photo was  taken in Malaysia. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: "One question per question", please

Comment: I suspect the whole point of the project was for you the learn how to use resources, not get others to your work. :)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is [*Tabernaemontana divaricata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabernaemontana_divaricata), a shrub native to India, Burma & Thailand and commonly cultivated throughout tropical Asia. Like most members of the Apocynaceae family (subfamily Apocynoideae) it has fragrant flowers and white, milky latex (sap) in the stems.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like Plumeria to me:  The rhododendron of the tropics.  Does it smell wonderful?[picture of Plumeria](https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.nOehcfEJY7dmtKCepe2LgQEsCz&pid=Api)  Apocynaceae cannabinum...the stuff most leis are made from.  Large shrub small tree.

Answer (score 1):

Crepe jasmine
"Tabernaemontana divaricata" commonly called pinwheel flower, crape jasmine, East India rosebay and Nero's crown is an evergreen shrub native to South Asia and now cultivated throughout South East Asia and the warmer regions of continental Asia.
Scientific name: Tabernaemontana divaricata
Courtesy: Wikipedia